# Array.Sort() allocating a large amount of memory

Tags: c#, performance, .net-5, memory-efficient

I'm working on a visualization that runs at 60fps. Part of that visualization is sorting the items on screen based on their position. I'm using

```
Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, int index, int length, IComparer<T> comparer)
```

which is allocating almost 1MB of `Comparison<T>` per second, which causes the GC to run frequently, which causes framerate hiccups.

I've tried several variations of `Array.Sort` and they're all allocating, including the one that accepts `Comparison<T>` (which is also insufficient because it lacks `index` and `length` parameters).

Is there any way to sort an array in C# (.NET 5) without allocating large amounts of memory?

**Update:** Here's a repro,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace New_folder
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
        // Empty
    }

    public class EmptyClassComparer : IComparer<EmptyClass>
    {
        public int Compare(EmptyClass x, EmptyClass y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EmptyClass[] emptyClasses = new EmptyClass[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                emptyClasses[i] = new EmptyClass();
            }
            EmptyClassComparer emptyClassComparer = new EmptyClassComparer();
            while (true)
            {
                Array.Sort(emptyClasses, 0, 50, emptyClassComparer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the allocations after 30 seconds on an old machine,

[image: Allocations of Comparison]

Comment: What function are you passing? Perhaps that is what is doing the allocation

Comment: I think I would use a sorted list/dictionary, then the items are sorted as they are added and you don't have to manually sort them.

Comment: The allocation is happening within Array.Sort(), regardless of what I pass for IComparer. The items change after they're added to the array, and they change every frame.

Comment: A quick perusal through the various issues suggests that, if this is a legit issue, it's almost certainly different for .NET 6+, since `Array.Sort` has in fact received extensive attention to performance in .NET Core (and still does), e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35175. What is the `T` you are sorting? For primitive types you really shouldn't be seeing allocations. For a non-primitive type the sort is of course partially dependent on the implementation of comparison (which is in turn dependent on equality, if using the default).

Comment: I added code that reproduces the issue. It occurs even with an empty class and an empty comparer. It also occurs if I remove the code that creates the empty classes and sort an array of null values.

Comment: Two ideas: 1. Make `EmptyClass : IComparable<EmptyClass>` (with a proper implementation) and don't pass a `Comparer` at all. This should invoke `Comparer.Default`. 2. Make `EmptyClassComparer` a `struct`, not a `class`. Except in very unusual cases, there is no compelling need for a reference type here. I can't test at the moment, but I would expect either approach to eliminate (heap) allocations altogether (at least in recent versions of the runtime, where the interface calls can be completely devirtualized; I don't know if .NET 5 is far enough along for that as well).

Comment: Also note that .NET 5 has just gone out of support; it is very worth seeing if you can move up to .NET 6, as each new release of Core brings performance improvements. As a bonus .NET 6 is LTS and will be supported for quite a bit longer.

Comment: I'm guessing it's some kind of bug. I can't see anywhere in the current code that would do this.

Comment: Also (can't believe I forgot this!) make sure you are *not* running your code under the debugger to test this since that can disable all sorts of optimizations; use BenchmarkDotNet with release settings if you want to get an accurate impression of allocations.

Comment: Switched to a struct. Passed in `Comparer<EmptyClass>.Default`. Switched to .NET 6. Ran in Release mode. All changes had the same allocations.

`IComparable<EmptyClass>` seems to prevent allocation in all versions, including .NET 5 Debug mode.

The problem is that they're compared differently in different situations, and I was trying to separate concerns, but I suppose I could hack it in with a static flag at this point.

Comment: It's weird because something in the back of my brain is telling me there were optimizations made with regards to delegate allocations (in cases where there are no closures), so I really wouldn't expect `Comparison` instances to pile up. It's definitely something that is at least amenable to optimization, if someone were to put in the legwork. Delegate allocation isn't always avoidable, but this is one instance where I'd expect the runtime to do better.

Comment: I switched to using `IComparable<T>` and a static `ThreadStatic` flag in my real app and it has prevented the unnecessary allocations. It's ugly, but it works.

In general, I've noticed that the framework has a lot of unnecessary allocations. I've had to reimplement a handful of types in order to avoid it.

Comment: Well, "unnecessary" is in the eye of the beholder. Once you have a garbage collector it's kind of a shame not to use its power by pre-emptively micro-optimizing every allocation, might as well stick to C in that case. :P Having said that, every new release does see allocation optimizations on hot paths of expensive and/or common operations, and things like `Span` and `ref struct`s are slowly but steadily marching into areas that previously knew only heap allocations. That said, .NET fundamentally remains GC based; those who need Rust know where to get it.

Comment: Perhaps, but a lot of the allocations are just negligence more than anything. I wouldn't mind the GC if they gave us more control or gave us the ability to turn it off completely during critical moments (Unity's .NET GC allows this). Random 5ms halts are a death knell for many applications.

There's TryStartNoGCRegion(), but it's flaky to the point of being useless.

I've thought of porting everything into Unity just to have the ability to turn off the GC.

Comment: FYI I posted a new thread on GitHub about this issue: [The Array.Sort with custom comparer allocates memory](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69701).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your observations. 64 bytes are allocated per `Array.Sort` operation on my machine, as well as on dotnetfiddle.net:

```
var random = new Random(0);
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Before Sort: [{String.Join(", ", array)}]");
var comparer = Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y - x); // Descending
const int loops = 1_000_000;
var mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
{
    Array.Sort(array, 1, 10, comparer);
}
var mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
Console.WriteLine($"After Sort:  [{String.Join(", ", array)}]");
Console.WriteLine($"Allocated:   {(mem1 - mem0) / (double)loops:#,0} bytes per loop");
```

Output:

```
Before Sort: [5, 10, 11, 8, 12, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 9]
After Sort:  [5, 12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9]
Allocated:   64 bytes per loop
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/989boX).

It seems to me like something that could be optimized in the .NET standard libraries. As a workaround you could use the `Sort` extension method below, that doesn't allocate. It accepts a [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1) instead of an [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1) though:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this T[] array, int index, int length,
    Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    Span<T> span = new(array, index, length);
    MemoryExtensions.Sort(span, comparison);
}
```

Usage example. Like before, with these two changes:

```
Comparison<int> comparison = (x, y) => y - x; // Descending
//...
array.Sort(1, 10, comparison);
```

Output:

```
Before Sort: [5, 10, 11, 8, 12, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 9]
After Sort:  [5, 12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9]
Allocated:   0 bytes per loop
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZw6XA).

It seems that it's also a little bit faster.

---

**Update:** I opened a new thread [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69701) about this issue, and I got the feedback below:

> Allocation tracking shows that allocation is delegate `Comparison<int>`.
>
> Allocated [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/80a5260004d82d6dd04aa2603cae354522b8eeb0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/ArraySortHelper.cs#L308).
>
> Due to the lack of value delegate, I'm afraid there's nothing we can do now.
>
> My suggestion is to use `Comparison<T>` instead of `IComparer<T>`, and cache the delegate via lambda or field.